# Twitter API for modeling graphs in Twitter

Tags: java, api, twitter, graph, social-networking

Which Twitter Library would give me the capability to model graphs and networks in terms of analyzing patterns and data visualization? I am most comfortable with Java and C# however, I could use C++.

Feel free to recommend other languages, or even approaches! (It is unclear to me which library to download and why it should matter, shouldn't Twitter keep them all up to date?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter only maintains a list of [Twitter Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries), but doesn't endorse any.  Here's the list:

If you're working with C#, my library, [LINQ to Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/), is on the list.

What the libraries will give you is access to the data, which you can take and manipulate for your own purposes.